# WallpaperChanger scaled centered

Tags: desktop-background

I am using Cortina WallpaperChanger.

"scaled" is very nice for large images, but is horribly for small images.

"centered" is very nice for small images, but is horribly for large images.

I want both :) e.g. "scaled" for large images AND "centered" for small images.

Is there an option, or indeed "another" WallpaperChanger, which offers both ?

Thank you.